# HTTP 404 - /docs/appdev/ on fresh netbeans tomcat 7 install

Tags: tomcat, documentation, http-status-code-404, java

As part of re-installing NetBeans 7.0.1, I had Tomcat 7.0.14 installed too on my PC. I created a manager role too. I can access `http://localhost:8084/manager/html` successfully.

```
<role rolename="manager-gui" />
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

However, when I try to access documentation, like `http://localhost:8084/docs/setup.html`, I get a `HTTP 404 resource not available`. I checked in the installation directory and `/webapps/docs/setup.html` does exist.

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing? Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here is the Host content of `server.xml`:

```
  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

    <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
         Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"  
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" resolveHosts="false"/>

  </Host>
```

I could not find any `catalina.out` files in the log directory (or elsewhere).

Comment: What does `<Host>` element in `server.xml` look like? Did you take a look at `catalina.out`?

Comment: @quanta Sorry for the late reply, I had to perform a couple of tests to double-check my installation, but the issue still remains. I have edited my question with info.

Comment: `catalina.out` file is located at `$TOMCAT_HOME/logs`, e.g: `/usr/share/tomcat6/logs/`.

Comment: @quanta Yes, I know, I checked my /logs directory and it is empty. I re-installed NetBeans 7.0.1 including Tomcat from scratch and it is still empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of the `CATALINA_BASE` environment variable. It's in the top of the Apache Tomcat Output window in NetBeans:

```
Using CATALINA_HOME: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.14
Using CATALINA_BASE: /home/user/.netbeans/7.0/apache-tomcat-7.0.14.0_base
```

The value of `CATALINA_BASE` is different than `CATALINA_HOME`. `CATALINA_HOME` is where Tomcat's binaries are and settings are in `CATALINA_BASE`. Tomcat runs those webapps which have a config in this (`CATALINE_BASE`) directory. The exact place is (in my case) `/home/user/.netbeans/7.0/apache-tomcat-7.0.14.0_base/conf/Catalina/localhost`.

Just put a `docs.xml` to the 
`/home/user/.netbeans/7.0/apache-tomcat-7.0.14.0_base/conf/Catalina/localhost` folder with the following:

```
<Context docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/docs" />
```

Then restart Tomcat.

Comment: Woaw, it works. I would have never found it by myself... Thanks !!!